# Strange Notation for Collection of Sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

My professor used this notation for a collection of sets: $\{A_{\lambda} \}_{\lambda}$.

What's the purpose of this extra subscript on the right curly bracket? I usually just go with $\{A_\lambda\}$ and specify an element as $A_i$ with $i$ as an element of the index set. Would the element of the collection $\{A_{\lambda} \}_{\lambda}$ be some $A_{\lambda_i}$ or something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, it's just indicating what the index is.  The fear is that $\{A_\lambda\}$ could be regarded as a set with a single member (the set $A_\lambda$), which probably wasn't the intention.  If we had an indexing set $\Lambda$ and another set $A_\lambda$ for every $\lambda \in \Lambda$, the full-blown correct notation would be $\{A_\lambda\}_{\lambda \in \Lambda}$ or $\{A_\lambda \mid \lambda \in \Lambda\}$.  Since that's overkill, the $\Lambda$ is often not written in the former.

At any rate, imagine the chaos if you had doubly-indexed sets $A_{ij}$ and only wanted to consider one index as varying.  Then you would definitely want to write $\{A_{ij}\}_i$ or $\{A_{ij}\}_j$ to indicate which is varying and which has been fixed.